# leaflet/ mapquest map and table

Tags: leaflet, popup, mapquest

i have a table and a leaflet/mapquest

I try to open en popup when i click on a item in the table
i do a listener but that don't work

Is there someone who can help me

THANKS

```
//JS
    function geocodeMap() {
    var adresses1 = adresses.slice(0,99);
    var adresses2 = adresses.slice(100,199);
    L.mapquest.geocoding().geocode(adresses1, createMap);
    }

          
function createMap(error, response) {

// Initialize the Map

          var map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
            layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('map'),
            center: [45.7621209,4.8348726],
            zoom: 14
          });
map.addControl(L.mapquest.control());


 // Generate the feature group containing markers from the geocoded locations
          var featureGroup1 = generateMarkersFeatureGroup(response);

 // Add markers to the map and zoom to the features
          featureGroup1.addTo(map);
    //      map.fitBounds(featureGroup1.getBounds());
 function generateMarkersFeatureGroup(response) {
          var group = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
            var location = response.results[i].locations[0];
            var locationLatLng = location.latLng;
 var ntravaux =travaux[i];           
var j = i+1;
var ndossiers = '<div id="3.0">'+dossiers[i]+' <br>'+ntravaux+'<\/div>';
// href="https://ads.grandlyon.fr/adscs/pages/dossier/Resume.aspx?nomDossier='+dossiers[i]+'">'+dossiers[i]+'<\/a> 
var ntypeD = typeD[i]; 

if (ntypeD == 'PC') {var couleurType='flag-FA0909-' } 
else if (ntypeD == 'DP')     {var couleurType='flag-FAC009-'}  
else if (ntypeD == 'PD') {var couleurType='flag-FF00EF-'}
else if (ntypeD == 'CP')  {var couleurType='flag-08FF00-'}
else  {var couleurType='flag-'}
            // Create a marker for each location
            var marker = L.marker(locationLatLng, {
                    icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://assets.mapquestapi.com/icon/v2/'+couleurType+j+'.png'
         })
            })
           //  .bindPopup(location.street);
        .bindPopup(ndossiers);
        
            group.push(marker);
          }
          return L.featureGroup(group);
        }
        
        
        //listeners
       window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

  for (let item of document.querySelectorAll('[id^="_recreated__bookmark__"]')){
   let nom = item.textContent;
    setupListeners(nom);
  }
  });
    
  
function setupListeners(nom){
    item.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      marker['nom'].openPopup();
    
    });
  
}

//End listerners

}
</script>
<script src="https://../jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    
    var myTable = jQuery("#__bookmark_1");
    var thead = myTable.find("thead");
    var thRows =  myTable.find("tr:has(th)");
    
    if (thead.length===0){  //if there is no thead element, add one.
        thead = jQuery("").appendTo(myTable);    
    }
    
    var copy = thRows.clone(true).appendTo("thead");
    thRows.remove();
          $('#__bookmark_1').dataTable( {
        "iDisplayLength": 25
      } );
    });

//HTML

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; empty-cells: show; width: 100%;" id="__bookmark_1">
                                    <col style=" width: 5%;"></col>
                                    <col style=" width: 15%;"></col>
                                    <col style=" width: 18%;"></col>
                                    <col style=" width: 15%;"></col>
                                    <col style=" width: 22%;"></col>
                                    <col style=" width: 15%;"></col>
                                    <col style=" width: 15%;"></col>
                                    <col style=" width: 0.1%;"></col>
                                    <tr class="style_5" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <th >
                                        <div>N°</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th >
                                        <div >Nom du dossier</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th >
                                        <div >Demandeur</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th >
                                        <div >Adresse des travaux</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th >
                                        <div >Description des travaux</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th >
                                        <div >Surface plancher</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th >
                                        <div >date de dépot</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th ></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr valign="top" align="left">
                                        <td >
                                            <div id="point">
                                                <a href="#1.0">1</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div>DP 069 381 21 01544</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div>MAIRIE /div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div>Montée des Carmélites</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div>Réalisation d'une fresque murale</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div>
                                                <div style="visibility:hidden">&#xa0;</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div>2 juil. 2021</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div style=" overflow:hidden;"><script type="text/javascript">var monadresse = "Montée des Carmélites";
    var monadresse1 =   DanaMethodReplace("replace",monadresse, "'", "\'"); 
    var monadresse2 = ', Lyon, France';
    var monadresse0 =  monadresse1 + monadresse2;
    var newLength = adresses.push(monadresse0);
    var newLength2 = dossiers.push('DP 069 381 21 01544');
    var newlenght3 = typeD.push('DP');
    var mestravaux = "Réalisation d'une fresque murale";
    var newlenght4 = travaux.push(mestravaux)
    </script>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" align="left">
    <td>
    <div id="_recreated__bookmark__1">
    <a href="#2.0">2</a>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div>DP 069 381 21 01497</div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div>VILLE </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div>26 Rue du Bon Pasteur</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div>Modification de clôture</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div>
                                                <div style="visibility:hidden">&#xa0;</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td >
                                            <div>28 juin 2021</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <>
                                            <div style=" overflow:hidden;">
<script type="text/javascript">var monadresse = "26 Rue du Bon Pasteur";
    var monadresse1 =   DanaMethodReplace("replace",monadresse, "'", "\'"); 
    var monadresse2 = ', Lyon, France';
    var monadresse0 =  monadresse1 + monadresse2;
    var newLength = adresses.push(monadresse0);
    var newLength2 = dossiers.push('DP 069 381 21 01497');
    var newlenght3 = typeD.push('DP');
    var mestravaux = "Modification de clôture";
    
    var newlenght4 = travaux.push(mestravaux)
    
    </script>                       </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the table click event firing?

If so, are you getting an error message?

If not, are any popups opening?

Is the marker variable available in the setupListeners function?

Comment: How can i know that the table click is firing ?

Comment: That's outside of the MapQuest functionality, but you can put an alert of log statement in the "click on a item in the table" event to confirm that the event is indeed being fired. Once that happens, we can help open the marker popup.

Comment: sorry but the table is a build automatically (birt) and i can't add an alert of log

Comment: The table will need to have an event or link to open the marker popup. The table event is outside of the MapQuest function so you may want to ask that question outside of this question. Once that event is set up, it can use the Marker.togglePopup function. Example of setting up the popup is here.
https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.3/examples/map-with-markers-circles-polygons/

Comment: Thanks, I have a link in the table but i don't know which javascript code i had to implement to open the good pop on the map, 
i have not found in the MapQuest documentation any example with an external link which open a pop up

Comment: The link in the table is a simple html link 

<div id="_recreated__bookmark__1">
    <a href="#2.0">2</a>
    </div>

Comment: You can have an array of markers and the table can refer to the index of the marker in that array. Then that marker can get the togglePopup function called on it. I use a var pois = L.featureGroup(); then add the markers to that pois.addLayer(...) and finally refer back to that marker when the external event is fired "<div onclick = 'pois.getLayer(" + poidx + ").togglePopup()'>" + text + "</div>"

Comment: i resolve my pb with an event listener on the <tr> THANKS !